# Firefox adjusts the microphone volume level on the computer, but not Chorme

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio, web-audio-api

It seems that Firefox is somehow able to automatically control the microphone input volume level on my computer, and in real-time it adjusts the level to either low & high, depending on my how loud I speak on the mic.

[The Windows Sound configuration dialog on my computer for the microphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sw8P.png)

I used this link to test for this feature: 
https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/index.html

How can I achieve the same on the Chrome? Is there a special Chrome setup for this? Or, is there a Chrome plugin for this, or even a 3rd-party plugin?  Also, is it possible to accomplish this using JavaScript after the end-user has granted browser access to the microphone?

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, you remove this section of code:

```
            "mandatory": {
                "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                "googHighpassFilter": "false"
            },
```

(My pitchdetect demo is explicitly cancelling the AutoGainControl and echo cancellation stuff in Chrome.)  You can't change it after calling getUserMedia (though you can call getUserMedia again).

Comment: Go it working in Chrome.  I initially was pointing to the wrong mic; its all good now; thanks!